# Radar Snr improvement

Tags: dsp, modulation, radar

I have a simple radar [module](http://www.rfbeam.ch/fileadmin/downloads/datasheets/ProductBrief_K-LC5.pdf) (k-band) that is capable of fm modulation and it provides both I and Q as baseband outputs. I like to extend the measurement range of this module by just signal processing options. (I.e. Without changing any hardware)

1. Would modulation help in terms of range? I can generate any signal such as triangle, sinus etc at the FM input of the module. (I know some range info could be obtained but I am after SNR, range knowledge is not material to my objective)
2. Currently I only use I to do my calculations. Could I also use Q together with I to reduce noise or improve SNR ? (I couldn't find any literature to that effect but I think there could be some gain in SNR if I use this additional signal)

Comment: In case you want to make an FMCW radar usually a triangle modulation is used so that the target distance translates linearly into a frequency change. A different modulation does not affect SNR as far as I know. What does help is averaging. Average over many measured results and the noise should go down but not the reflection.

Comment: What are you using the radar for? I and Q are both needed for radar imaging. I would expect that utilizing both would improve SNR somewhat in any application, and give you the ability to extract phase information. But I would like to know what you are doing with the radar data.

I believe FMCW can typically produce I/Q data much faster than gated, pulsed radar, and with much lower peak power. But in order to get I/Q data from FMCW, you need to do some signal processing (I think you need to compute the analytic signal, but I am not a signal processing guy).

Comment: @mkeith I use radar to measure speed. (Simple Doppler measurement) However I am trying to improve my distance. The radar subsystem already provides I and Q.

Comment: I don't think modulation will help you. But if you use both I and Q, you can calculate the phase angle at each sample point, and compute the rate of change of phase much more accurately and quickly and then you would not need to do any FFT or anything. I think this would be  very advantageous. You will need to sample fast enough so that the doppler frequency is not aliased.

Comment: @mkeith I cannot see the signal in the frequency domain after certain distance. The noise of the module make it difficult to see the signal. Fft is not an issue. I have computational power. I am looking for literature that shows me how I can use both I and Q to reduce noise or improve snr.

Comment: Well, start by just storing the I/Q pairs. When you do your FFT, feed in complex numbers instead of real valued numbers. This should improve  SNR. By discarding the Q data, you are throwing away signal. This wouldn't require a HW change, and is easy to try, and easy to do a side-by side comparison of the exact same data processed two different ways. Sorry I have no literature, but this seems intuitively obvious. There are other things I would try if it was me, but it is difficult to explain.

Comment: Are your I and Q baseband signals identical in amplitude but shifted in some way or aligned?

Comment: Using both I and Q would slightly improve your SNR, but the main thing it would do would be to let you distinguish positive from negative frequency shift in a baseband output - ie, let you distingush approaching from receding doppler.  With just one you get only the magnitude of the shift but not the sign.

Comment: Is the target of interest guaranteed to be the  only thing moving in the scene? If the radar is not one-of-a-kind, are you at liberty to provide information about the manufacturer and model? Is there a range of Doppler shifts that are expected, so that you can digitally filter the signal prior to processing?

Answer (score 4):

There are very strong limits on what you can do to improve SNR. After all, your received signal consists of a low level reflected signal, and a noise signal **in the same frequency range**, that cannot be filtered out.

A couple of things to do

a) Don't throw away any signal that you don't need to, use both I and Q

b) Reduce the detection bandwidth as much as possible, to reduce the amount of noise around the signal, without reducing the signal. How much you can do this depends on the phase noise of your transmit and receive LOs.

As the I and Q outputs are produced by the module mixing the received signal with the transmit LO, you will be able to use synchronous averaging. As the phase noise of the oscillator (from which we could deduce coherence time) is not specified, we cannot figure out up to what range this will work well.

You will be able to make some test measurements. Your range agnostic signal processing consists entirely of DC averaging the I and Q signals, with no FM applied. Do this with no reflector in  range. The result will be your DC offset. Now repeat with a reflector present, and see the result.

Unfortunately in using DC averaging, you will be reducing noise at the cost of DC drift. A little thought experiment around the setup of getting the DC offset above will illustrate this. What about transmit signal that 'leaks' straight into the receiver? Won't that appear in I and Q? Yes, anything in the environment that puts transmit signal in the receiver will affect your result. Your ability to detect remote (weak return) targets confidently rests entirely with the stability of these unwanted returns. If they are stable, you can subtract them, if not, you can't tell them from returns.

This is where the FM modulation comes in, to add range information to your returns. With range information (you said you didn't want it in the OP, but it turns out to be necessary if you want sensitivity to weak signals), you can tell the difference between a weak reflection 10m away, and a change of leakage signal at the module/antennae.

With FM, the receiver is mixing the returned reflections not with the LO that was transmitted, but with an LO whose frequency has changed since it was transmitted. If you gate your reception properly, and use triangle FM (triangle in frequency deviation, not triangle in voltage at the tune port, they are only the same for linear tuning), then a substantial part of your received signal will be at an IF frequency of +/- the distance.

Unfortunately, to use synchronous averaging, you need the offset **phase** to be stable at the IF. Although in theory, a stable FM will give you stable PM, in practice any slight change in FM gain and FM drive level will make the phase deviation wander around, the unwanted deviation getting worse as the time/distance increases (PM is the integral of FM after all), precisely the conditions where you want to use this technique to dig your signal out of noise.

The technique is therefore to gate your received signal, to use it at times when the FM offset is consistent. Then take an FFT, to encode reflection distance against phase. Then do it again and again, summing the FFTs, so the consistent target phase adds as voltage, and the inconsistent noise adds as power, gaining you 3dB SNR every time you double the number of readings in the sum. Then ignore reflections with a phase shift indicating they are from Tx to Rx leakage at the module, and accept ones from further out.

Obviously the FFT will be unable to distinguish between signals that have had a phase shift of \$\theta\$, and a shift of 2\$\pi\$+\$\theta\$, so you will need to choose your FM deviation and modulation rate to suit your maximum range, so that significant reflections never exhibit more than 360 degrees reception phase shift.

Obviously, a moving target will be smeared out over several range phases, just as VCO phase noise will smear a stationary target out. The latter can be used as a limit to determine how fine an FFT it's worth using.

Comment: I added a link to the radar module. I would appreciate if you could expand on your answer based on the module datasheet.

Comment: @TGG try that for size

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is build an [LPI radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_probability_of_intercept_radar).  Yes, you can get significant extension in range for a given transmit power (actually, energy-on-target is what matters) through the use of signal processing.

The basic idea is that because you know what pulse you transmitted, you can use that information to pull the received pulse up out of the noise.  You convolve your received signal with the transmitted signal, which will amplify the reflection but will not amplify the received noise.  By the way, you want to do the convolution in the frequency domain as it's far cheaper: O(n+n*logn) vs O(n^2) in the time domain.

The terms you need to look up and understand are "pulse compression" and "time-bandwidth product".  Do some reading on FMCW and Barker-coded radars.

Using both I and Q will help as it gives you twice the information for a given bandwidth.  Don't try to compute phase and magnitude, do all your signal processing in the complex domain.  In the complex domain sampled at f Hz, you have an unambiguous representation of f Hz of bandwidth, unlike in the real domain where Nyquist says you get only f/2 Hz.  Using both I and Q means you could in principle look at a narrower bandwidth and thereby reduce thermal noise by up to 3dB.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a DSP guy, so I don't know if this is sound. But I would try unwrapping the phase. (Remove DC bias first). I believe that noise is as likely to have positive as it is negative rotation from sample to sample. But the Doppler signal will consistently advance the phase in one direction. So when you unwrap the phase, you will get a straight line whose slope corresponds to the actual Doppler shift. I believe this will provide substantial processing gain. It is not difficult to try, once you start capturing the I/Q data.

Good luck.